# Boost intersection

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have a problem with boost intersection algorithm. I am not sure if I did an error or it is a bug.

```
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersection.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> BoostPointXY;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<BoostPointXY> BoostPolygon;

    BoostPolygon polyOne, polyTwo;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
            "POLYGON((45, 4), (45, 17), (44, 19), (44, 22), (50, 20), (51.5, 17), (58, 4), (60, 0), (53, 0), (45, 0), (45, 4))",
            polyOne);
    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
            "POLYGON((-10, -5), (0, 25), (43, 25), (45, 20), (50, 20), (60, 0), (5, 0), (5, -5), (-10, -5))", polyTwo);
    std::vector<BoostPolygon> multiPoly;
    boost::geometry::correct(polyOne);
    boost::geometry::correct(polyTwo);
    boost::geometry::intersection(polyOne,polyTwo,multiPoly);
    std::cout << "Size of Multi " << multiPoly.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Using Boost "
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minior version
              << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
              << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of Multi 0
Using Boost 1.55.0
```

But the size of the multiPolygon should be 1 or? When it is a bug, can someone test it with the current boost 1.57 ? I can't change my boost version at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: same output for 1.57

Comment: is the polygon invalid ? Or I did a mistake?

Comment: have you tried plotting the polygons? This is what I got with my quick attempt: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cng6.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WKT data is invalid:

```
boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((45  4, 45  17, 44  19, 44  22, 50  20, 51.5  17, 58  4, 60  0, 53  0, 45  0, 45  4))", polyOne);
boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((-10  -5, 0  25, 43  25, 45  20, 50  20, 60  0, 5  0, 5  -5, -10  -5))", polyTwo);
```

Your sample just used many invalid(?) inner rings.

Now you get:

```
Size of Multi 1
```

[image]

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78fad466e61f0e75)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersection.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> BoostPointXY;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<BoostPointXY> BoostPolygon;

    BoostPolygon polyOne, polyTwo;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((45  4, 45  17, 44  19, 44  22, 50  20, 51.5  17, 58  4, 60  0, 53  0, 45  0, 45  4))", polyOne);
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((-10  -5, 0  25, 43  25, 45  20, 50  20, 60  0, 5  0, 5  -5, -10  -5))", polyTwo);

    boost::geometry::correct(polyOne);
    boost::geometry::correct(polyTwo);

    {
        std::ofstream svg("/tmp/svg.svg");
        boost::geometry::svg_mapper<BoostPointXY> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
        mapper.add(polyOne);
        mapper.add(polyTwo);

        mapper.map(polyOne, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(153,204,0);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(polyTwo, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(204,153,0);stroke:rgb(204,153,0);stroke-width:2");
    }

    std::vector<BoostPolygon> multiPoly;
    boost::geometry::intersection(polyOne,polyTwo,multiPoly);
    std::cout << "Size of Multi " << multiPoly.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i saw this wkt read somewhere. U used boost 1.57 now or? On boost 1.55 i still have the output zero

Comment: (Please type proper words.) You're messing something else up. Boost 1_55 gives "Size of Multi 1" just the same